# Yes to repeat program/No to exit

Tags: java, loops

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Console;

        public class Activity2
       {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        int choice;
        int time;
        Console cons = System.console();
        if (cons==null)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }
        name = cons.readLine("Enter your Name: ");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("\nMenu");
        System.out.println("\n[1] Network Engineer\n[2] Software Engineer\n[3] Full Stack Developer\n[4] Technical Support");
        
        
        System.out.print("\nEnter your job(Choose a number from the menu): ");
        choice = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter no. of hours present at work: " );
        time = scn.nextInt();
        
        
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            int gsalary = 1200*time;
            int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
            
            cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
            System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 1200 per hour.");
            System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
            System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
        }
        
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            int gsalary = 800*time;
            int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
            
            cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
            System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 800 per hour.");
            System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
            System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
        }
        
        if (choice == 3)
        {
            int gsalary = 600*time;
            int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
            
            cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
            System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 600 per hour.");
            System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
            System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
        }
        
        if (choice == 4)
        {
            int gsalary = 500*time;
            int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
            
            cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
            System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 500 per hour.");
            System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
            System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample output:

Enter your name: Matsuno Chifuyu

Menu

[1]Network Engineer

[2]Software Engineer

[3]full Stack Developer

[4]Technical Support

Enter your job(Choose from the menu): 3
Enter no. of hours present in work: 36

Hello Matsuno Chifuyu!
Your job salary as a Full Stack Developer is 600 per hour.
Your gross salary for this week is 21600.
Your net salary for this week is 19008.

Do you want to input another employee? (Yes or No)

How can I manage to do a loop that If answered yes the program will restart and if no the program will exit

Comment: Put `while(true)`, and `break` if no was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish this is to throw your code in a loop and then break if the user inputs no. See the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        // put your app logic here
    
        System.out.println("Do you want to input another employee? [Y]es/[N]o");
        if (!in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y") {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It just repeats the program but doesnt ask the user

Comment: @Eljinx Instead of having 4 to 5 if blocks , try to use "switch" statement so that you can have a default case if inputs other than 1,2,3,4 are given or else the while loop execution will not be in a proper way.

For Example if you have entered the input as 5 instead of 4 , The code straightly jumps to the if block where it asks whether you want to input another employee or not...So pls take care of the negative scenarios as well.